# Saas MongoDB + Node.js Architecture

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

guys!

Sorry if there's another question like mine. I just searched a lot but couldn't find an answer.

Let's say I'm willing to create an business management app for schools, and let's say I really need one database for each user.

I'm now using Express + MongoDB + Angular. I just stuck at this question.

How should I build it? I mean, is there any MongoDB driver that allow, I don't know, something like 200 concurrent connections in differente databases? If yes, is there enough documentation for it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You cannot use need per database for user. Cuz there will be a question how You'll do relation on app level between N of databases? Use http://mean.io/ it has all You need.

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't understand what you said.

Comment: You said: "let's say I really need one database for each user"  - so why You need 1 DB per user it's not flexible.

Comment: Mean or SailsJS, gives You ability quickly develop what You want. Just watch Youtube tutorials.

Comment: Ok, but why? I mean, how are those tools different?

Comment: MEAN = Mongodb, Express, Angular, NodeJS if You want quick results so learn to work with that app stack. SailsJS - is Rails-like framework for quick development also, it has also real-time, ajax-like features.

Comment: Hey man, I think you didn't read my question. But thank you.

Comment: Ohhh, if You think about MongoDB OR(D)M that will be Mongoose. It's easy and concrete. http://mongoosejs.com/  about many connections: it's about creating variable that keeps handler of connection

Comment: In nodejs You don't need to create connection on every request. You just have one connection like:  var connection = mongoose.connect(); and use it everywhere.

Comment: My point is that I need each client to save their data on my app. I couldn't merge a lot of businesses' information in only one DB.

Comment: Pedro, You're totally wrong. All big companies, big apps has one max 2 dbs to keep huge amount data. But it may have replications for performance, it's unnecessary for the beginning, even when it has big traffic too, because of nosql structure.

Comment: I've made same hugeness app, and it uses 1 db instance, it's fast, it isolates data of each user or organization.

Comment: If You have 200 users it does not mean You have to use 200 dbs, it's inneficient, and nobody have done that ever.

Comment: Now you said something we could work with. What is that approach? Do they use different collections for each user?

Comment: In mongodb You've collections, You've documents in collections - so Your app must do data integrity and isolation.

Comment: Pedro, watch this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrkvMnm4Mnc  and this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-o_VGpJP-Q0 also look for `data modeling` tutorials. You'll understand how to do that.